# spectrum of Banach algebras

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ is a locally compact group (non-Abelian)

Why $sp(L^1(G))$ , i.e. the set of all nonzero bounded multiplicative functionals on $L^1(G)$ is a locally compact group.

Even for any noncommutative Banach algebra A, why $sp(A)$ is a locally compact space?

Can you give me a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a (noncommutative) Banach algebra, a character (i.e. a multiplicative linear functional) is automatically bounded.  Then consider the set $\Sigma(A) \subseteq A^*$ of nonzero characters with the weak-$*$ topology inherited from $A^*$.  Then  $\Sigma(A) \cup \{  0 \} $ is a weak-$*$ closed subset of the unit ball in $A^*$, which itself is weak-* compact.  Thus $\Sigma(A) \cup \{  0 \} $ is weak-$*$ compact, so $\Sigma(A)$ is locally compact.

Of course, for a general Banach algebra you may not have many characters, but that's a separate issue...

Comment: Just to add: the fact that $0$ compactifies this space is the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: Phil, I'm not sure what you mean.  What is the Riemann Lebesgue lemma for a general Banach algebra?

Comment: Doesn't the usual proof that a character is continuous use that a character is unital?

Comment: Yes, but can't you just extend the character naively to the unitalization of the algebra?

Comment: @MTS: Yes!  Sorry, silly question...